# UILabel shifts to left when UITableView Loads and gets fix after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

i have a tableView where i putted a UILabel and am changing its left Constraint's Constant dynamically : 
my TableViewController

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TableViewCell




    //let totalLength = (cell.slider.frame.width + (cell.postNumber.frame.width + cell.negNumber.frame.width + cell.middleConstraint.constant))
    let differnceToRemove = (cell!.postNumber.frame.width + cell!.negNumber.frame.width + cell!.middleConstraint.constant) / 2

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell!.slider.value = 0

    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell!.slider.value = 1.0
        }
    else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        cell!.slider.value = 0.5
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3 {

        cell!.slider.value = 0.25
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        cell!.slider.value = 0.33
    }


    cell!.contraint.constant =  ((( CGFloat (cell!.slider.value) ) * cell!.slider.frame.width) + cell!.paddingConstraint.constant) - differnceToRemove



    let leftTrackImage = UIImage(named: "vLine")
    cell!.slider.setThumbImage(leftTrackImage, forState: .Normal)
    cell!.slider.setThumbImage(leftTrackImage, forState: .Selected)
    cell!.slider.setThumbImage(leftTrackImage, forState: .Highlighted)


    return cell!
}
```

my TableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var paddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var postNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var negNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var middleConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var contraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var slider: CustomSlider!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
```

image 1 when tableView Loads : [image: image 1 when View loads]

image 2 when i scroll ones through it  :

[image: image 2 after scrolling]

after scrolling on my tableView every labels set on to their exact position , tried so many things like re arranging my Constraints in story board , clean build etc still no luck if anybody knows whats wrong then please do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the layout after changing the constraint:

```
cell!.contraint.constant =  ((( CGFloat (cell!.slider.value) ) * cell!.slider.frame.width) + cell!.paddingConstraint.constant) - differnceToRemove
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

See the "Laying out Subviews" section of the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutIfNeeded) document.

Auto Layout can be tricky, so I am referencing Apple's guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).

**EDIT**

You could also  use these methods in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
tableView.setNeedsLayout() 
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

We are forcing the table view to reload it's self and thus do another layout pass. This is a work around you still should workout what is the difference between the first layout pass and the second (due to you scrolling). I would start with your custom table view cell.

Comment: firstly thanks for responding , well i just tried what you suggested but still no luck :( @fragilecat

Comment: you can try making the same call on the tableView it's self. tableView.layoutIfNeeded() Also I would move the constraint code to be the last thing you do before you return the cell

Comment: well i tried your new updated answer and with tableView too still  no change , now going through your links

Comment: Try changing the differnceToRemove to a fixed value - for trouble shooting.

Comment: cell!.postNumber.frame.width + cell!.negNumber.frame.width + cell!.middleConstraint.constant, print these values out in the method or use the debugger to see if they have meaningful value.

Comment: output is `62.0` of `(( CGFloat (cell!.slider.value) ) * cell!.slider.frame.width) + cell!.paddingConstraint.constant`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112512/discussion-between-fragilecat-and-remy-boys).